# Migrate SVN Repo WITHOUT svnadmin OR svnsync

Tags: svn

I have a remote SVN server that I'm required to upload our existing local repo to. There are a lot of revisions and doing it manually would be very time consuming. However, I've been faced with several roadblocks, all of which our system admins have told me "don't matter".

EDIT: To be clear, there is an existing, empty remote repository.

- I would like to use 'svnadmin load' with a dump file but *the repository is URL-only* - no path. I have no access to the actual repository, which svnadmin requires, and the admins will not grant me access.
- I had thought to use svnsync, but the admins will not enable the pre-revprop-change hook required for svnsync to work.
- The server has a custom admin interface which does not have a load command, and the admins have not provided an alternative to load dumps.

What are my options here? I need a way to load a svn dump, or equivalent, without using svnadmin, without using svnsync, and with only URLs to access the repo.

Answer (score 3):

> What are my options here?

I would suggest the administrative actions to "stop the sabotage"

## Techical solution

Subversion 1.7

> svnrdump.exe help load
>
> load: usage: svnrdump load URL
>
> Load a 'dumpfile' given on stdin to a repository at remote URL.

If you cannot use svn 1.7  (locally), you can try trick with local repo (any version), DVCS-bridge (in order to get all changesets in DVCS-repo) and push to remote SVN-repo

In any case, you have to have sufficient rights in repo (user-password)

Comment: Thanks. I agree, the admins are clearly not familiar with SVN here! :D As for the advice on using svnrdump from SVN 1.7, I'll try it once it's installed. It might take a while!

Comment: Okay, svnrdump failed because "Target server does not support atomic revision property edits" and "pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is nonexistent" and "error setting property 'rdump-lock'" etc. So that's not going to work. How would the other technique work (DVCS bridge) - say, with git 1.7? I haven't really done anything with git, let alone the git-SVN bridge.

Comment: 1st error - mea culpa, don't read pre-req for svnrdump - it's **1.7 on target**. pre-revprop-change hook must be added on server-side - is it possible?

Comment: No problem, at least now I'm on the latest version. ;)

Comment: And no, the admins will not add the pre-revprop-change hook. They also won't upgrade the repos to 1.7...

Comment: Git-way with git-svn. Never do it, but here git-svn small howto http://www.viget.com/extend/effectively-using-git-with-subversion/. Your first steps - create local repo and `svnadmin load` dump to it. Later - just follow HowTo, I hope

Comment: Okay, I got as far as creating a git-svn repo that has the contents of the dumped SVN repo, but now I need to do _whatever I need to do_ to push the git-svn repo to the _remote_ SVN repo. I've tried several things with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Add one more remote into git? dcommit to new remote? Maybe ideas from here will be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609872/how-can-i-use-two-svn-projects-and-corresponding-git-svn-branches-with-a-single/632063#632063